# Getting a Depth Map From 3D Points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, 3d, coordinates

How to get a depth map of 3-D points? I have a ply file consists xyz points of a point cloud. I want to get the depth map of this. Which coordinates should I extract? I'm planning to use numpy array and put the coordinates into this array. How will I get this? I've looked but if there is a repository please let me know maybe I've missed it. I'm a newbie and any help is appreciated.Thanks.

EDIT:
Can I convert this 3-D data to 2-D? With 2-D points I can get the depth information I need. Is there a chance to converts this a 2-D image?

Comment: To obtain a depth map, you first need to position the camera within the 3D space.  Then you need to use the extrinsics and intrinsics of the camera to help define the depth.  Without both of these, what you ask for is impossible as there are an infinite number of depth maps you can obtain within this point cloud due to the infinite number of camera positions you can use in space.

Comment: I have also images from the exact same point with the point clouds. Would this help me?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that "exact same point with the point clouds".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: create a camera model and use homography and projection transformations to generate 2d images. Maybe you will need tesselation of the point clouds. You can use z-buffering to ignore the occluded points.

Comment: @rayryeng I'm working in a simulation. Camera and virtual LiDAR are on the same point. When the point cloud is generated, camera is replaced with the virtual LiDAR. With this, they are on the same position.

Comment: @Jenny so you already have virtual camera. Do you have intrinsic camera calibration parameters?

Comment: @Micka Could you please give me an example algorithm/code?

Comment: If you have a calibrated camera, for each 3D point, you can use the camera extrinsics and intrinsics to determine if the 3D point is within FOV of the camera.  After this, you'll have the corresponding 2D point in the image, so you now have a correspondence between pixel and depth.  Because the point cloud will be sparse in nature, you will most likely have a lot of holes so you will have to figure out how to fill in these holes - either through inpainting or by tesselating the point cloud as Micka suggested.

Comment: @Micka Yes, I have calibration configurations in order to get the pixel coordinate from the 3D position.

Comment: Some code that elucidates your point would help.  As it stands, your question is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.